# Starting app with login page when tab bar controller is present

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have conditional code in my app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method that uses HTTP requests/responses to determine if the user is logged in already. I'm running into serious hierarchy problems, and my question is this: should I be starting my app with the login page (and make the app delegate conditionally load my tab bar when the user is logged in already), or start with my tab bar (and make the app delegate conditionally load my login page)?

This is my storyboard currently

[image]

Comment: Note if rdelmar's suggestion/answer works for you, please accept it as an answer when you get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the tab bar controller the root view controller of the window, and present the login controller from the viewDidAppear method (without animation) of the controller in the first tab. Also, you should not go backwards in a storyboard with a segue, unless you use an unwind segue. Segues (other than unwinds) alway instantiate new controllers, so you're not actually going back to a previous controller, you're instantiating a new one. This will cause more and more controllers to be added to your hierarchy as the user navigates back and forth.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks. @rdelmar